# InfoPath template not saving changes

Tags: extract, infopath, infopath2010

I have inherited a system which was developed in InfoPath 2010 but saved in 2003 format.

A former colleague was asked if he would make changes to the forms.  Last week, I was approached to make the same changes.  When I opened the form in edit mode I noted that the changes were already saved.  I tried making a couple more changes and both saved and deployed them.  When I opened the form again, all changes were lost.

In addition, I tried to extract data from multiple forms at once but this has stopped working too and is now only letting me extract data from one form at a time.

It is only this past few weeks that this has been happening.  Prior to that, we were problem free.

Has anyone come across this before and, if so, how did you fix the problem.